# JQuery Ajax POST throwing an empty error without making the request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, post

I have a function that makes an Ajax request for any anchor. The request method can be GET or POST. In this case, I want to make a POST without using a form but the Ajax request throws an error before even sending the request. The error has the value "error" and all error/failure description variables are "".

```
 function loadPage(url,elem_id,method,data) {
    ajaxLoading(elem_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success:function(data){
            $("#"+elem_id).html(data);;
        },
        error:function(request,textStatus,error){
            alert(error);
        }
    });
 }
```

When the function is called the params are these (copied from the js console):

```
data: "partial=yes"
elem_id: "page"
method: "post"
url: "/projects/2/follow"
```

As asked, here is the code that calls the loadPage function.

```
$("body").on("click","a.ajax",function(event) {
    var _elem = getDataElem($(this));
    var _method = getRequestMethod($(this));
    var _partial = getRequestPartial($(this));
    handlers.do_request(event,$(this).attr("href"),_elem, _method, _partial);
});

var handlers = (function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.do_request = function(event,url,elem_id,method,data) {
        event.preventDefault();

        loadPage(url,elem_id,method,data);
        history.pushState({selector:elem_id,method:method,data:data},null,url);
    };
}());
```

After the failure of the Ajax request, the request is made by default and it responds sucesss. In all I have read, this seems to be a valid way to make a POST request (that doesn't need a form).

Am I doing something wrong in the function? Why is the error information empty?

Thanks

EDIT:

I have been thinking, for a POST from a "form" that function works, when the variable "data" is made with the serialize function (e.g. "var data = $(this).serialize();"). Could it be that the format of the "data" when I make a POST without a "form" is wrong in someway? Maybe the JQuery Ajax function doesn't accept a simple string like "partial=yes" as data when a POST is made. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: are you saying the request and textstatus variables are empty

Comment: Should `post` be capitalized?  It is in the docs.

Comment: can you post the code showing how you are calling `loadPage`?

Comment: textStatus has the value "error" and error has the value ""

Comment: Added the code that calls the loadPage function

Comment: Log the parameter values in loadPage to console.

Comment: Try making the request in a browser that allows you to debug network requests (i.e. Chrome), or run the request through a proxy (i.e. Charles) and see if a request is made, and if so what the status of that request is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not solve the problem, neither could find the reason why it was happening. Although, I found a way around, by using a hidden empty form instead of an anchor with the method 'POST'. For a form, the function worked nicely.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced this problem and after an hour or two, thought to try setting cache to false. That fixed it for me.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: method
});
```

Unfortunately, when I removed cache again, my request was working as if it had never had a problem. It seems as if setting `cache:false` made something 'click'.

Oh well.

Comment: You server reply should not allow for caching if the data you are trying to retrieve (Assuming a `GET`, although the question is about a `POST`) is dynamic. Then the `cache: false` should not be required.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the type parameter is in all caps, i.e. `'POST'` and not `'post'`.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, so both shouldn't necessarily work.  I checked the jQuery source (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L455), and it looks like they convert the type parameter to uppercase, so I guess it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function loadPage(url,elem_id,method,dat) {
    ajaxLoading(elem_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: dat,
        success:function(data){
            $("#"+elem_id).html(data);;
        },
        error:function(request,textStatus,error){
            alert(error);
        }
    });
 }
```

I'm wondering if you are running into a problem using a variable named after a keyword. If this doesn't work, try calling loadPage with no arguments and hard coding all of your ajax parameters, just to see if that works.

Comment: Tried that now, no success. Still throwing an error without even sending the request. Thanks for the answer although.