# $.ajax post request going into get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, http-post

Been banging may head all over the place to get an understanding of what's going on.
Here is my jquery ajax request:

```
function newContact() {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                // url: rootURL,
                url: "http://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/api/det",
                dataType: "json",
                //data: formToJSON(),
                data: '{"name":"tom","last":"test","email":"test@west.coast.com","password":"xyz"}',
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        alert('Welcome');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log(' Error: ' + errorThrown);
                }
        });
}
```

Now, i have tested the url with curl and it works, i've checked whether the input's val() gets populated, which it does and i really do not understand why when i fire the function i get a GET request as follows:

```
[11:08:47.607] GET http://xxxxx.com/?name=&last=&email=test%40email.test.com&passwrd=asdf&passwrd2= [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 40ms]
```

This is what gets sent to the server. Now if i open firebug's console i see the following:

```
POST http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/det


jquery.min.js (line 6)
HeadersPost
Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  81
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host    xxxxxxx.com
Referer http://xxxxxxxxx.com/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

which i am not really able to understand. what's this POST mentioned above when apache gets sent a GET req?

And moreover i am out of ideas on what could be the problem or how to start troubleshooting, being a complete newbie with ajax/json.

any idea that can shed some light here would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Now thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182233/jquery-ajax-post-throwing-an-empty-error-without-making-the-request) i have been able to move one little step forward: after adding the method post to the form i have been able to make a post request, however it goes to / instead of where i'd expect to (url: "http://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/api/det").

Comment: How is the function triggered? Is it within an event handler?

Comment: I think [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) violation

Comment: The funtion is triggered by jquery click function:

        $("#subm").button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-person"}}).click(function() {
                newContact();
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was stopping the form from being submitted by using the method `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$("#subm").button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-person"}}).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  newContact();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Method in the api (http://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/api/det) you are calling is of **Get** type, and you are calling in "POST" type may be the situation.

Check the methods type in the Api.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer
In fact not, and as a proof of it if i send a json post request to that url data gets inserted fine. I tested it wth curl